# how to read and write with different scripts to a serial port same tim?

Tags: python, python-2.7, serial-port, pyserial

I currently have two scripts one to write to the serial port and another one to read from the serial port, both are working fine with the individual jobs. What I also wanted to try is running both the scripts at the same time and I would like to see the write input to the serial port as an output from the read script. I am missing something in between, this particular case is not working.

```
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = baudrate
ser.port = port
ser.timeout = timeout
```

A sample of read:

```
while True:
   line = ser.readline().encode('hex')
   print line
```

I have also tried with

```
While True:
    bytesToRead = ser.inWaiting()
    ser.read(bytesToRead)
```

I write to the serial port using `ser.write(command)`

Comment: What exactly is not working? Could you show the error messages you get? How are you trying to execute two parts of the code (reading/writing) at the same time? Why are you using deprecated `inWaiting()`?

Comment: I mean both are working independently, but when I run both at same time I am not receiving the input I entered in writing side from the reading end

Comment: I was asking how exactly you are running both scripts in parallel and if you are getting any errors because you can have only one connection to a specific serial port open at time. Maybe one of your scripts has configured port but closed connection.